# Wordpress add_submenu_page function not working

Tags: php, wordpress, menu

I need to create a new menu and a sub menu item for the wordpress administrators. The menu is working fine but the sub menu items ( a duplicate sub menu for the main menu item is being created automatically.. I don't want that ). Both the sub menu items has their href attribute blank. I don't understand what the menu slug is. Please help..

```
    // create custom plugin settings menu  
       add_action('admin_menu', 'retail_create_menu');

       function retail_create_menu() { //create new top-level menu
          add_menu_page('Retailers', 'Retailers', 'administrator', __FILE__, 'generate_retailer_list', 'http://localhost/apsm/wp-content/themes/wp-mediamag/functions/retail.ico'); 
          add_submenu_page( __FILE__, 'Add Retailers', 'Add Retailers', 'administrator', 'add_ratilers.php', 'retailer_submenu_callback');
       }
```

The file are inside a folder in my theme...

---

[image: This is what the menu looks like]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One simple hack to hide that duplicate menu:

```
add_submenu_page(
    '__FILE__',        // parent slug, same as main menu slug
    '',        // empty page title
    '',        // empty menu title
    'administrator',        // same capability as parent
    '__FILE__',        // same menu slug as parent slug
    'generate_retailer_list',        // same function as parent
)
```